# php login page nothing happens

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

**I have problem with login page. When I load page first time this happend:**

[http://postimg.org/image/o36250qk5](http://postimg.org/image/o36250qk5/)

**And when I type username and password, wrong or true I got this screen:**

[http://postimg.org/image/v53zr7u5x](http://postimg.org/image/v53zr7u5x/)

**This is my code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>LOGIN PAGE</title>
    </head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
    if($_POST) 
    {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];     
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
            or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s') AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($username),
            mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if($count == 1) 
        {
            $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location:index.php');
        } 
    }
        else {
            session_destroy();
            echo ("Error: that username and password combination does not match any currently within our database");
        }
?>
<form method='post' action='login.php'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' /><br />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form>
<br>
<a href="index.php">INDEX</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please check it and tell me what I done wrong, thanks...**

Comment: Quick edit your code to not use mysql but mysqli, quickly before they see!

Comment: I am not sure I understand you...

Comment: I done it all, problem with first time loading page solved, but still when type right username and pass I got error...

Comment: How is the original password stored? The hash generated by the `md5()` function will not match the hash generated by the MySQL `PASSWORD()` function nor the hash generated by the MySQL `OLD_PASSWORD()` function. Try printing out the result of `md5($password)` and the password as stored in the database and compare them.

Comment: U were right @taxalot, passwords didn't match... thx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Move your else condition inside the `if($_POST)`

```
<?php @ob_start(); 
 @session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>LOGIN PAGE</title>
 </head>
<body>

<?php
if($_POST) 
{
    require_once 'config.php';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];     
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
        or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s') AND password='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($username),
        mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location:index.php');
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        echo ("Error: that username and password combination does not match any currently within our database");
    }
} ?>

<form method='post' action='login.php'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' /><br />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form>
<br>
<a href="index.php">INDEX</a>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: Use mysqlii_* functions or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You have started your output and not initialized `session_start()`. This function must be called before any output, so here can be solution.

Your code will look something like this:

```
<?php session_start(); // we start sessions before output ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>LOGIN PAGE</title>
    </head>
<body>

<?php
    if(isSet($_POST) && $_POST) 
    {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];     
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
            or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s') AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($username),
            mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if($count == 1) 
        {
            $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location:index.php');
        } 
        else {
            session_destroy();
            echo ("Error: that username and password combination does not match any currently within our database");
        }
    }
?>
<form method='post' action='login.php'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' /><br />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form>
<br>
<a href="index.php">INDEX</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I edited

```
if($_POST)
```

to

```
if(isSet($_POST) && $_POST)
```

and

```
            if($count == 1) 
            {
                $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('Location:index.php');
            }
        }
            else {
                session_destroy();
                echo ("Error: that username and password combination does not match any currently within our database");
            }
```

to

```
            if($count == 1) 
            {
                $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('Location:index.php');
            } 
            else {
                session_destroy();
                echo ("Error: that username and password combination does not match any currently within our database");
            }
        }
```

Because if you will not send any data, the sessions will be destroyed. I believe you want if sent data are incorrect, then delete any sessions.

Comment: You could replace `if(isSet($_POST) && $_POST)` with `if(!empty($_POST))`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd suggest adding a note about not using MySQL extension for new code. Perhaps add a link to http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Well for one `if($count == 1)`, you don't have an else or else if that handles a failure to find the user in the database.

I'd move the `else` clause you have to after that `if` and put an `else` after the parent `if` that provides a message about missing input parameters instead of nothing matching.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for contact us form working perfectly, you just need to edit this form according to your need and add to your html code as post form. i am using this same code on my website.

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "your@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "Your email subject line";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

   }



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

   }



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

 if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

  $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

   }

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

  $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

 if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

 if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

   $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

    }

 if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

  died($error_message);

   }

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

 $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

 ?>



  <!-- include your own success html here -->



  <h4 align="center">Thank you for contacting us. We will revert you back.</h4>



 <?php

   }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all don't use MySQL, please use MySQLi,
Second, try to not use the sprintf function. Try using this code

```
mysql_query('select * from users where username = UPPER($username) and password = UPPER($password)"
```

Sorry im using a phone to answer this

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this answer. You correctly recommend MySQLi extension over MySQL, but then provide code for the latter. Your code trusts user input which is *very* insecure. OP was at least escaping the input with `mysql_real_escape_string`. You need to escape the input or use parametrized queries for security. Your code would never return results unless the password was stored in plain text which is very insecure. Your code will cause a MySQL error if either $username or $password contain anything other than digits since text needs to be enclosed in single quotes.